# How To Disable Merge Picking in Odoo Push Rules

Tags: odoo, erp, odoo-16, warehouse

I use Odoo 16 CE

Here's the scenario:
I made 2 Operation Types:
Operation A (Internal Transfer) & Operation B (Delivery)
Operation A is used to list all the products that we need to consume internally
Operation B is used for approving the list from Operation A

Then, I used 3 Locations: WH/Stock (internal location), Location A (internal location), Internal Consumption (customer location)

Then, I made the Route like this:

Pull From WH/Stock ->to Location A

Push To Location A -> Internal Consumption

Now, the problem is when I made 2 Operation A, all the requests are merged in Operation B.

Operation A:
A0001 = Product A = 2 Qty
A0002 = Product B = 2 Qty

Operation B:
B0001 = Product A 2 Qty & Product B 1 Qty

What I want is:

Operation A:
A0001 = Product A = 2 Qty
A0002 = Product B = 2 Qty

Operation B:
B0001 (reference A0001) = Product A = 2 Qty
B0002 (reference A0002) = Product B = 2 Qty

How do we achieve this? Is the Push rules that made it merged?

Comment: AFAIK the merging thing can't be configured at all. It highly depends on which process is starting/creating the procurements using the rules. Look into `stock.move._key_assign_picking()`. It's used to group stock moves by a key in `stock.move._assign_picking()`. Most of the rules you create are starting by creating the moves at the end of the chain, so your Operation B. So splitting up the moves has to be done on that process already.